# Line Chart with date and time on X axis

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am working with line chart using ZedGraph and C# in Visual Studio 2010.
The values ​​are coming from serial port.
The date and time are entering the X axis, but each interval the number of seconds to change and it seems that this weak and lacking harmony.
How to solve this?

[This video shows the problem.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEuhtqlKYwQ)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try using:

```cs
        myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "HH:mm";
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStepAuto = false;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStepAuto = false;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit = DateUnit.Minute;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorUnit = DateUnit.Minute;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStep = minor;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = major;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = Min;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = Max;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = false;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = false;
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = min_rr;
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = max_rr;
```

For `MinorStep` and `MajorStep` you must use some value like 3, 5, 30 etc.
For `Max` and `Min` use eg:

```cs
XDate Min = new XDate(1999, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
XDate Max = new XDate(1999, 1, 1, 0, 30, 0, 0);
```

In [Changing axis type in ZedGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951465/changing-axis-type-in-zedgraph) you have example with DateAsOrdinal X Axis.

I hope it helps. Cheers.